# AngularJS filter causes infinite $digest loop exception

Tags: angularjs, filter, infinite-loop

The problem I am trying to describe here is quite complex and I'm aware that my English is far from perfect, so if anyone will have enough patience to read this through I'll be very grateful.

Ad rem: I have a custom directive (called *metadata*) in which I use "angularjs-dropdown-multiselect" module:http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/ to provide a multiple selection field. It works fine, but here's the problem: the directive is called several times (as I need several fields of that type) and some of these fields are interdependent. For example, I have two fields: 'Living place' and 'Person'. When the user selects one or more living places in the multi-select field, some of the 'Person' field options should be filtered out to leave only people that live in the selected places. I can't make it right: no matter what I try, the filtering process triggers an 'infinite $digest loop' exception.

The list of the possible choices for each field is extracted from the json data file (called meta_data.json), which has the following format:

```
[{"person": "JeJu1929", "living-place": "Zabrid'"}, 
 {"person": "VM1996", "living-place": "Velykyj Bereznyj"},
 {"person": "VB1957", "living-place": "Zabrid'"}]
```

So, when the user chooses 'Zabrid', the options list of the 'Person' field should contain two entries: 'JeJu1929' and 'VB1957'. 
The choices user made are stored in the separate factory function (called *queryKeeper*) as well as the data from the file mentioned above.

The architecture of the whole process is as follows:

1. The factory function reads the json file (*meta_data.json*) containing data and stores it in a list of objects (*metaValues*)
2. In a directive controller (invoked for, say, 'Living place' field) the data object (*metaField*) is read and a list of all possible options is obtained
3. angularjs-dropdown-multiselect requires that the options list consists objects in the format `{id: value, label: option-name}`, so in the process of obtaining the options list, each option is converted from the string type to the required object format, so - for the 'Living place' field - I end up with the options list as follows:

   [{id: 'Zabrid', label: 'Zabrid'}, {id: 'Velykyj Bereznyj', label: 'Velykyj   Bereznyj'}]
4. When the user chooses some options in the field, this information goes to the factory function (and is stored in the variable *metaFields*)
5. Let's say, that we want to filter out the 'Person' field options according to the choices user made in the 'Living place' field. The filter function gets these choices (from the *metaFields* variable), the data object (*metaValues*) and a list of options to be narrowed down (which contains in our example three options: "JeJu1929", "VM1996", "VB1957"). If the user chose in the 'Living place' field an option 'Zabrid', the filter function throws out the person "VM1996" as its living place is not 'Zabrid'.

To this point, everything works fine. But when the new options list (which is a subset of the old list) is returned by the filter, the $digest loop fires off again and again and finally the 'infinite $digest loop' exception is thrown. I thought that the problem is in comparison of objects (that even when the objects are in fact identical, angular still thinks that they are different), but this is rather not the case: when filter function is called for a 'Person' field options, it gets as parameter, say, four options, and returns, say, two. Then the filter is called for other fields (like 'Living place' etc.) and once again for the 'Person' - with the same parameter (i.e. four options, not two) just like for the first time. This is confusing and I'm stuck.

---

The relevant parts of the code:

**file**: metadata.html (template)

```
<div>
        <div ng-if="meta.type == 'select'" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="values|matchValues:meta.name" selected-model="model" extra-settings="multiSettings" translation-texts="hint" checkboxes="true">
</div>
```

**file**: metadata.js (my custom directive)

```
corpus.directive('metadata', ['queryKeeper', 'gettextCatalog', function(queryKeeper, gettextcatalog) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'jsapp/languageQuery/metadata/metadata.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            index: '=',
            place: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope, gettextCatalog) {

            // function obtains the list of all possible options for the field
            getValues = function () {
                values = [];
                metadata = queryKeeper.getMetaValues ();
                name = $scope.meta.name.slice (5);  
                for (i = 0; i < metadata.length; ++i)
                    if (typeof metadata[i][name] != 'unknown')
                    {
                        var tmp = angular.copy (metadata)[i];
                        tmp['name'] = name;
                        tmp['id'] = metadata[i][name];
                        tmp['label'] = tmp[name];
                        values.push (tmp);                      
                    }
                values = values.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a[name] > b[name]}).reduce(function(a,b){if (a.length == 0 || a.slice(-1)[0][name] !== b[name]) a.push(b);return a;},[]);
                return values;
            }

            $scope.meta = queryKeeper.getMeta($scope.index, $scope.place); // provides access to the field data, like field name, choices made etc.
            $scope.values = getValues ();   // actual options list (to be filtered)
            $scope.model = [];  // stores the user choices

            $scope.multiSettings = {showCheckAll: false, buttonClasses: 'btn btn-default meta', dynamicTitle: false, scrollable: true, scrollableHeight: '150px'}; // angularjs-dropdown-multiselect settings
            $scope.hint = {buttonDefaultText: $scope.meta.hint};

            // watch function that sends the user choices to the factory function

            $scope.$watchCollection ('model', function (newValue) {
                queryKeeper.setMetaMulti ($scope.index, $scope.place, newValue);
            });         
        }
    };
}]);
```

**file**: corpus.js (main module)

```
corpus.factory('queryKeeper', ['loadLanguages', 'loadMetaData', function(loadLanguages, loadMetaData) {

    var metaFields = [];
    var metaValues = [];

    loadMetaData.getMetaFile('settings/meta_data.json').then(function(response) {
        metaValues = angular.fromJson(response);}); 

    return {

        getMeta: function(i, place) {
            return metaFields[i * 3 + place];
        },
        setMetaMulti: function (i, place, item) {
            metaFields[i * 3 + place].multiValue = [];
            for (j = 0; j < item.length; ++j)
            {
                metaFields[i * 3 + place].multiValue.push (item[j].id);
            }
            return item;
        },

    }
}]);

    corpus.filter ('matchValues', ['queryKeeper', function (queryKeeper) {
    return function (values, name) {
        metaSet = queryKeeper.getMetaAll ();
        var tag = '';
        if (name == 'meta_living-place')
            tag = 'variety';
        else if (name == 'meta_person')
            tag = 'living-place';
        else
            return values;
        console.log ('init:', name, values);
        metadata = queryKeeper.getMetaValues ();
        newValues = [];
        var found = [];
        for (i = 0; i < metaSet.length; ++i) {
                if (metaSet[i].name == 'meta_' + tag) {
                    found = metaSet[i].multiValue;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (typeof found == 'undefined' || found.length == 0)
            return values;
        for (j = 0; j < values.length; ++j) {
            for (i = 0; i < found.length; ++i)
                if (found[i] == values[j][tag])
                    newValues.push (values[j]);                 
        }
        console.log ('new:', name, newValues);  
        return newValues;
    }
}]);
```

### UPDATE

It took me a while, but I've created JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17604/. To my surprise, in my code was another issue I wasn't aware of: in my module I used 'ngAnimate' module, which prevented filterning of the list of choices. When I removed this dependency, the list began to behave correctly. I'm curious why. Still, the infinite $digest loop problem remains.

Comment: this filter does not look idempotent, filters **cannot** modify the data they are filtering.

Comment: sorry, I'm too tired to try to solve your problem right now, but I will point out a few potential issues with your code: (metadata.js) 1. is `getValues` a global function? 2. `sort(function(a,b){return a[name] > b[name]})` this looks like a silent bug to me.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the filter does not modify the data (_value_) - it only constructs a new list (_newValues_), where the matching elements of _value_ are added

Comment: @Stefan Baiu: 1) `getValues` is defined in the _metadata_ directive controller, I'm not entirely sure if that makes this function global in angular... And if yes, where is the source of trouble?

Comment: @user1785295: if there's no `var` the function will become global (hopefully there's no need to tell you why this is a bad practice). Anyway, please post the markup where the `matchValues` filter is used. Just a hint: check the `$watchCollection` in the `metadata` controller. You can start debugging your problem there.

Comment: @user1785295: Where is the `metadata` directive being used?

Comment: Ok, I edited metadata.html file, adding a filter call `options="values|matchValues:meta.name"` (another stupid overlook). I suspected the $watch function too, so I inserted a console.log statement into it (as well as into the filter function). Result: when I choose an option in the 'Living place' field, immediately the $watch function goes (only once), then the filter runs for every field I have in many iterations, ultimately triggering an exception. So I have doubts if that's really the source of trouble...

Comment: `metadata` directive is called from the another (outer) directive in the ng-repeat statement

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in a JS fiddle or something and share a link. Also I was interested in the markup where `metadata` is being used.